# Как правильно присоединиться к процессу?

Tags: python, python-3.x, процесс, pymem

Использую библиотеку `pymem` .При попытки присоединить к `client_panorama.dll` `base address` . 
`base_address = (0x05590E40)`
`client=pymem.process.module_from_name(pm.process_id,"client_panorama.dll").base_address`
Выводит ошибку:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'base_addres'

Вот мой код:

```
import pymem    
import pymem.process    

dwEntityList = (0x4C3D0CC)
dwGlowObjectManager = (0x520DA28)
m_iGlowIndex = (0xA320)
m_iTeamNum = (0xF0)

pm = pymem.Pymem("csgo.exe")
print(pm.process_base)

base_addres = (0x05590E40)

client = pymem.process.module_from_name(pm.process_id , 
"client_panorama.dll").base_addres
```

Comment: Что выводит `print(pymem.process.module_from_name(pm.process_id,"client_panorama.dll"))`? None?

Comment: Попробуйте вместо `process_id` использовать `process_handle` [пример](https://github.com/srounet/Pymem/blob/30d8da9b54a5219930477505b7cedceb1fd39bec/pymem/pattern.py#L156)

Comment: `print(pymem.process.module_from_name(pm.process_id,"client_panorama.dll")` выводит None

Comment: Значит не смог найти модуль. По коду видно, что `None` вернется если не получится найти: https://github.com/srounet/Pymem/blob/30d8da9b54a5219930477505b7cedceb1fd39bec/pymem/process.py#L262

Comment: `client = pymem.process.module_from_name(pm.process_handle , "client_panorama.dll")` выводит `<pymem.ressources.structure.MODULEINFO object at 0x05770D50>`

Comment: Вот видите с handle нашлось :) Кст, не используйте круглые скобки для значений `(0x05590E40)` и т.п. -- очень похоже на конструкцию кортежа (`tuple`), да и просто лишнее в коде. Просто указывайте как есть, например `dwEntityList = 0x4C3D0CC`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Укажите вместо `process_id` – `process_handle`:

```
client = pymem.process.module_from_name(pm.process_handle, "client_panorama.dll").base_address
```

**UPD.**

Вот [тут](https://github.com/srounet/Pymem/blob/30d8da9b54a5219930477505b7cedceb1fd39bec/pymem/pattern.py#L158) встречается использование модуля:

```
base_address = module.lpBaseOfDll
```

поэтому думаю вам поможет:

```
module = pymem.process.module_from_name(pm.process_handle, "client_panorama.dll")
client_address = module.lpBaseOfDll
```

Comment: `AttributeError: 'MODULEINFO' object has no attribute 'base_address'`

Comment: module_from_name возвращает объект MODULEINFO, а у него действительно нет base_address: 
`https://github.com/srounet/Pymem/blob/30d8da9b54a5219930477505b7cedceb1fd39bec/pymem/ressources/structure.py#L306`. Зато у него есть lpBaseOfDll, мб это то, что вам нужно?

Comment: Спасибо большое ,`module = pymem.process.module_from_name(pm.process_handle, "client_panorama.dll")
client_address = module.lpBaseOfDll` это помогло